# Entity Framework 6 can't read all the rows in a database table

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have two tables in my database, `Agent` and `AgentInfo`.

One `Agent` maps to many `AgentInfo`s.

Database table's columns are like the following:

- `Agent` (Id, AgentInfo_Id, Name); AgentInfo_Id ref the latest AgentInfo added in database for this agent.
- `AgentInfo` (Id, Agent_Id, Status); `Agent_Id` tell which `Agent` the `AgentInfo` belongs to.

(cleaned some irrelevant column )

I created two models.

```
public class Agent
{
    public Agent()
    {
        this.AgentInfoes = new List<AgentInfoe>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? AgentInfo_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual AgentInfo AgentInfo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AgentInfo> AgentInfoes { get; set; }
}

public class AgentInfo
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Agent_Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
}
```

and the map

```
// AgentInfoMap
this.HasRequired(t => t.Agent).WithMany(t => t.AgentInfoes).HasForeignKey(d => d.Agent_Id);

// AgentMap
this.HasOptional(t => t.AgentInfo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.AgentInfo_Id);
```

and the function code

```
var agentInfo = db.AgentInfos.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == req.AgentInfoId);
var agent = agentInfo.Agent;
var status = agent.AgentInfoes.Any(o=>o.Status==1) ?1:-1;
```

In here `agent.AgentInfoes` can't load all the `AgentInfo` that belong to this agent.

There are 5 rows that the `AgentInfo`'s foreign key `Agent_Id` are equal `agent.Id` in database, but I only get 2 `AgentInfo` with this code.

What is wrong?

Comment: Just guess. There are 5 AgentInfo for that Agent but only 2 AgentInfo with Status equals to 1.

Comment: @yyou no, the 2 AgentInfoes I get, their status are (-1,1) , and all of them's Status are (2,-1,1,0,2)

Comment: Why does `AgentInfo` have an `Agent` property as well as `Agents` collection? Are you creating one-many or many-many?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I creating one-many model. agentInfo.Agents   only have one object, and equals agentInfo.Agent

Comment: @Yizhi Well there's your problem: `.WithMany(t => t.Agents)`. You are mapping a many-to-many relationship in really round about way.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Ok,should it be `this.HasRequired(t => t.AgentInfo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.AgentInfo_Id)` ?   I rewrite it   and the problem still exsits

Comment: solved it . `var agent = agentInfo.Agent` do not get data in database.it gets data in cache or  memory. Using code like `db.AgentInfos.Where(v=>v.Agent_Id == agent.ID);` getting data in database can get a right result.